# "Method not supported" when creating table via Thrift Server JDBC in Spark 1.5

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a instance of Spark 1.5 running a thrift server. My database manager (DBeaver) successfully connects to this thrift server. However, when I try to run the following piece of code:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    id int
)
```

I receive: **DBCException: SQL Error: Method not supported
  java.sql.SQLException: SQLException: Method not supported**

The interesting thing is, the table **is in fact created**. When I try:

```
beeline> show tables;
+------------+--------------+--
| tableName  | isTemporary  |
+------------+--------------+--
| test       | false        |
+------------+--------------+--+
```

If I try to create a similar table from beeline, it is created without any error messages.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> CREATE TABLE test02( id INT );
+---------+--+
| result  |
+---------+--+
+---------+--+
```

The question is, how to create tables via JDBC without receiving this error message?

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: That is pretty much the code. I try to run the CREATE TABLE inside DBeaver and receive the error. Inside **beeline** the same code runs without errors. I am suspecting it is some problem with the JDBC Hive driver and the latest Spark version (1.5.2). Anyways, I'm adding the beeline code to the post.

Comment: Hm - have you checked http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/news/ - they claim they fixed something with "object creation"...

Comment: I updated dbeaver, but the error remains. Nothing seems to be wrong with the thrift server log: http://pastebin.com/NtfkKx7r